# xshift of ybar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I `xshift` an `ybar` plot, so that number display will be aligned with the vertical left line of each bar instead of being in aligned to the center and the width of each bar to be exactly `25` (now it seems the bar is slightly bigger)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\pgfplotsset{compat/show suggested version = false}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    ybar,
    bar width = 25,
    minor tick num = 4,
    nodes near coords,
    ]
    \addplot[thick,fill=blue!50] coordinates {%
        (0,1)
        (50,0.3)
        (100,0.2)
        (150,0.2)
        (200,0.1)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `bar shift` option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\pgfplotsset{compat/show suggested version = false}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    ybar,
    bar width = 25,
    minor tick num = 3,
    nodes near coords,bar shift=12.5
    ]
    \addplot[thick,fill=blue!50] coordinates {%
        (0,1)
        (50,0.3)
        (100,0.2)
        (150,0.2)
        (200,0.1)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You also need 3 minor ticks if you aim for 25 increments

[image]

Comment: I knew the `bar shift=12.5`, but I was not aware that I needed, `minor tick num = 3`. Other solution would be to use the example in page 65 `pgfplots` documentation and set the first plot with `opacity=0`. But that is of course less efficient. Thanks